# Copy automatically only the color from one cell to another- EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I have cell `017`, the value and color of this cell is changing constantly due to a formula and conditional formatting.

Cell `O16` changes constantly due to a formula too but the formula and their values are different from cell `017`.

What I want is that cell `O16` contains the same color of cell `O17` automatically once the value of cell `017` has changed.

There should be a solution in VBA. I hope your help.

EDIT:

User [simoco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067523/simoco) has came up with a solution for Excel 2010 and later:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Range("O16").Interior.Color = Range("O17").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I use Excel 2007, Is there and equivalent to that code in 2007?.

Answer (score 2):

**Works only with Excel 2010 and later**

If your cell `O17` can be changed *only through formula*, use following code (this code should be used in `Sheet` module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Range("O16").Interior.Color = Range("O17").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

Otherwise, also add `Worksheet_Change` event with the same code.

Comment: I've tried your code but there's a message of error and that should be the reason of my problem. I use Excel 2007 in Spanish, the message says:" Error "4838" has produced in running time. The object doesn't accept this property or method".

Comment: as Tim mentioned, `DisplayFormat` was introduced only in Excel 2010

Comment: I'm trying to find it out, but not sure.. why not just add CF rules for O16 same as for O17?

Comment: The values for O16 are different. So, the color would be different for CF rules.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49160/discussion-between-simoco-and-creamstat)